# How to import JSON file with embedded array into Mongodb using Compass

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-compass

the JSON file is like :

```
{
"A": [
  {"above average": "more than average, esp. in amount, age, height, weight etc."}, 
  {"absolutely necessary": "totally or completely necessary"},
  ],
"G":[
  {"get back together": "to become a couple or a group again after being apart"}, 
  {"get better": "to improve"}, 
  {"get better (at)": "to improve in skill or ability"},
  ],
}
```

I encounter the error: "Operation passed in cannot be an Array", when use the "import file" function provided by the Compass.

What can I do or any alternative approach(python)?

I am expecting a easy approach.

Thanks!

Comment: @Lodinn Yes, sort of a hard way,  I am expecting a easy one. If I have no other choice, I will follow this way. Anyway, thank you.